# I want to implement datePicker using angular but it is calendar is not showing properly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am implementing datePicker using angular- material but the calendar is not showing properly

i tried downgrading the angular/material version but didn't work

// my ionc info looks like

```
         ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0
           Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.6
           @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

        Cordova:

           cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
           Cordova Platforms     : not available
           Cordova Plugins       : not available

        System:

           NodeJS : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
           npm    : 6.9.0
           OS     : Windows 10
```

```html
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>Date Picker</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-form-field>
         <input matInput placeholder="Select Date 
                [matDatepicker]="selectDate">
         <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="selectDate">
         </mat-datepicker-toggle <mat-datepicker #selectDate></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

// my dependencies versions

```
 "@angular/material": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.0.2",
```

Expected output is calendar with proper days and dates but getting only dates. also UI is not proper.

Comment: can you share stackblitz? or share the screenshot of the output

Comment: An screenshot, or console errors might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can try.

1. Try updating the material to >8 as you are using 5 and `@angular/material-moment-adapter` is on 8.
2. Make sure you are importing the necessary modules for `DatePicker`. You will require below modules in your case,

   ```
   MatDatepickerModule,
   MatFormFieldModule,
   MatInputModule,
   // MatMomentDateModule, // either this or MatNativeDateModule
   MatNativeDateModule
   ```
3. If it still doesn't work I have made a stackblitz, click on `date picker` and you will see a date picker with proper css and UI

   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yashpatelyk-material-components

Also if you attach screenshot of your output or stackblitz URL, we can help you debug better.